# Question on complete bounded distributive lattices

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, boolean-algebra

Suppose you have any complete bounded distributive lattice of the form $\langle \mathbf{A}, \wedge, \vee, 0,1 \rangle$. Now, suppose you have two $a,b \in \mathbf{A} $ such that $(a\wedge b) = 0$ where $a \neq 0$ and $b \neq 0$. Is it possible to find two $c,d \in \mathbf{A}$ such that $a \leq c < 1$, $b\leq d < 1$ and $(c \wedge d) \neq 0$.

Comment: Wait, I don't understand. If $c\ge a$ and $d\ge b$ then $c\vee d\ge a\vee b$, right? So if $a\vee b=1$ we must have $c\vee d=1$.

Comment: With respect to the current version of the question, what about the four-element Boolean algebra?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks for answering! In the case of the four valued Boolean algebra, wouldn't  $a \wedge b$ (where a and b are the "corners of the diamond") be the only option for $(a \wedge b)= 0$ ? So, if $c=a$ and $d=b$, then $c \wedge d = 0$. However, I am looking for an exampe where $c \wedge d \neq 0$. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, and I was saying that the four-element Boolean algebra shows that it is **not** always possible to find such $c,d$.

Comment: Hey! Sorry I should have phrased my question differently; can you provide an example where it is possible to find such $c,d$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a=(0,1,1), b=(1,0,0), c=a, d=(1,0,1)$, which satisfies all your prescriptions, and we obviously have $(c \land d) \neq 0$